# angular4:ng-content nested class based selection

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

As we all know in Angular4 we have support for `ng-content`.

In this, we can select based upon **class**, **element-name**, **attributes**.

I am trying to select element based upon class :
Here is my consumer component html :

```
 <my-component>
      <div class = "item">
        <div class = "item-small">small-item content</div>
     <div class = "item-large">large-item content</div>
    </div>

</my-component>
```

Now in my `my-component` template, I am trying to access `div` with class `item-small`.

My `my-component` template looks as follows:

```
<div class="my-component">
   <ng-content select = ".item>.item-small"></ng-content>
</div>
```

But it is not returning me anything.
Here is the plunk for this issue:

https://plnkr.co/edit/2hlL2GezNXRoLCD1FAPD?p=preview

What is the best option to handle such cases?

Kindly give right approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure only selectors are supported that directly match elements

This should work

```
".item-small"
```

but this not

```
".item>.item-small"
```

like with element or directive selectors.

Comment: This is not working. I have edited my question to  provide plunk for this problem.